# Splitting polyline into points at certain intervals

Tags: qgis

I am trying to split a polyline into points with 2m intervals in ArcGIS but I don't have the necessary license.

Is there a way that I can do this in QGIS?

I have drawn a hypothetical lake surface based upon a contour line and need to divide it.

Answer (score 4):

Using the GRASS plugin, you can split lines using v.to.points:

```
# convert line to points; dmax = distance between points
v.to.points -i -v -t in=osm_road out=osm_road_pts type=line dmax=90
```

You'll have to import the line layer into GRASS first. That's easy using e.g. v.in.ogr.qgis which accepts a layer which is already loaded into QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

With QGIS 2.2.0 you can use two plugins: QChainage to get the equally spaced points along the input polyline, and Points2One to assemble these points into a new polyline or polygon

Answer (score -1):

Use the Densify tool in ArcMap. The Densify tools allows you to add points to a line and you can set the distance between those points within the tool. For your case you can set the distance between the points to 2 meters. After using the Densify tool you can then use the Feature Vertices To Points tool to convert the line with all of those points into only points.

Comment: Asker has asked for QGIS solution, and states at outset that they do not have license for ArcMap.